# Javascript reg ex returns only one occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]
```

My following regular expression returns `[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]`

```
var re = new RegExp("\\[.+\\]", "g");
var arr = re.exec("[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]");
```

But I want to get [Key1], [Key2], [Key3]... all the available matches. How can I achive that?

Comment: Your `.+` is greedy so it's grabbing everything between the first `[` it encounters and the last `]` it encounters. If you change it to `.+?` it won't be greedy any more and it should work.

Comment: in that case i get only [Key1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]"; 
var res = str.match(/\[.+?\]/g);
```

***res*** contains an array of matches, you can use `res.join(",")` in order to obtain your string

Answer (score 3):

Use the non greedy modifier:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\[.+?\\]", "g");
//                 here __^
```

`re.exec` gives only the first match, if you want all the matches, you have to use `string.match(re)`:

```
var string = "[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]"; 
var re = new RegExp("\\[.+?\\]", "g");
var arr = string.match(re);
```

then `arr` contains `["[Key1]", "[Key2]", "[Key3]"]`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it would be simpler to do `"[Key1]+[Key2]+[Key3]".split('+')`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: Only if there're no `+` inside the `[ ]`

Comment: i get only [Key1] in this way